# Excel VBA 2010 - If-Then-ElseIf statement not recognizing string variables

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I have an Excel VBA macro with an `If-Then-ElseIf` statement that is within a `For-Next` loop. I'll show the code before describing the issue. I post the entire code just in case I'm wrong about thinking the problem lies within the If statement.

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

    Dim wsPasteTo As Worksheet, wbDATA As Workbook
    Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long

    Set wsPasteTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACP")
    NextRow = wsPasteTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2

    Set wbDATA = Workbooks.Open("\\cmicro.com\Shares\Amb\Amb-Probes\DataLogs\CQS-03-033-2012 Coax Shelf Cut Log R2.6.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wbDATA.Sheets("ACP")

        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            If Cells(i, "E") = "Angle" Then
                .Range("K2:L" & LastRow).Copy
                wsPasteTo.Range("I" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            ElseIf Cells(i, "E") = "Vertical" Then
                .Range("K2:L" & LastRow).Copy
                wsPasteTo.Range("D" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            Else
                .Range("K2:L" & LastRow).Copy
                wsPasteTo.Range("N" & NextRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

            End If

        Next i

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    wbDATA.Close False

End Sub
```

This macro copies data from another Excel workbook (let's call it the Copy Workbook) based on what's in column E of the Copy Workbook. Column E has 3 options for the user to choose: "Angle", "Vertical", and "n/a". I used data validation so the user must chose one of those 3 options from a drop down in all column E cells. Based on that, the macro pastes data into columns in a separate workbook, let's call it the Paste Workbook.

This code doesn't have errors, however all the data is being pasted into the wrong place in the Paste Workbook.

I think the problem is with the lines of code:

```
If Cells(i, "E") = "Angle" Then
```

and

```
ElseIf Cells(i, "E") = "Vertical" Then
```

because when I'm in debug mode, these lines are skipped as though the string variables "Vertical" and "Angle" aren't there in column "E". That's why all the data is going into one place.

I can't figure what is wrong with the code. I checked out column E in the Copy Workbook and there are no spelling/capitalization issues. Maybe a Case statement would be better for what I'm doing, but I'm not savvy with VBA and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please qualify the Cells Object correctly. They may be referring to the wrong sheet. Use something like `If Wb.Sheets("Something").Cells(i, "E").Value = "Angle"`

Comment: I think the With statement takes care of that, no? You did help me realize I forgot a dot (".") in front of Cells. After correcting that the data is now being pasted into ALL columns. Somehow the macro isn't distinguishing between "Vertical" and "Angle". It's taking all the data and pasting it twice. I think you're right about not qualifying the Cells object correctly.

Comment: Don't you need to increment `NextRow` inside your loop?  Unless there's only one set of data per file...

Comment: I'm not sure if I need it. I think I do. So the Copy Workbook is constantly being updated throughout the day. It's usually always open on a computer downstairs and users record data into it. The macro is linked to a Command Button in the Paste Workbook. When I press the button the macro runs. I'm worried that without 'NextRow' I might paste over previous data.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

Dim wsPasteTo As Worksheet, wbDATA As Workbook
Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim val, col 

    Set wsPasteTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACP")
    NextRow = wsPasteTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 2

    Set wbDATA = Workbooks.Open( _
          "\\cmicro.com\Shares\Amb\Amb-Probes\DataLogs\" & _
         "CQS-03-033-2012 Coax Shelf Cut Log R2.6.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wbDATA.Sheets("ACP")

        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            val = .Cells(i, "E").Value
            Select Case val
                Case "Angle": col = "I"
                Case "Vertical": col = "D"
                Case Else: col = "N"
            End Select

            wsPasteTo.Cells(NextRow, col).Resize(1,2).Value = _
                                .Cells(i, "K").Resize(1, 2).Value

            NextRow = NextRow + 1 'or whatever....

        Next i

    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
wbDATA.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: Was just about to post a similar solution with Select Case but I used `LCase(.Cells(i, "E").Value)` to avoid case sensitivity.

Comment: Sweet Case statement Tim. I've changed my code but before I run it, what does the    NextRow = NextRow + 1 do?

Comment: I tried it out and it works, but their are gaps in the columns where the data gets pasted. For example, column E in the Copy workbook has "Angle" in rows 3 - 10 and "Vertical"  in rows 11 - 17. In the Paste workbook the "Angle" data is in the correct column in rows 3 - 10 however the "Vertical" column is blank until row 11. This might be an issue with "NextRow" but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: My bad - it's not clear when to move to the next "destination" row: if there is only one "set" is data to be copied from the input file then you don't need to increment NextRow at all.  Otherwise you'd need to explain a bit more exactly how the data on the ACP sheet looks.  Also note you originally set NextRow based on column A, but when your code adds a row ColA is not populated, so if you run it again it may populate a row which already has data.

Comment: Both workbooks have a sheet called "ACP" which is confusing I know, but on the Copy workbook all the data I want is in columns K & L. In the Paste workbook I want to paste the data in columns D & E (for Vertical), I & J (for Angle), and N & O (for everything else). I tried running the macro without "NextRow = NextRow + 1" and all data was pasted over so there was only one entry in columns D & E and I & J. Although there were no gaps and the data was correctly placed. Also idk how to make code blocks in comments, so sorry for that.

Comment: I figured it out! I needed a NextRow for all 3 data types (vertical, angle, and n/a). I don't know how to post the working code through a comment. I'd like to so people can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

Dim wsPasteTo As Worksheet, wbDATA As Workbook
Dim NextRow As Long, LastRow As Long, i As Long
Dim val, col

Set wsPasteTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ACP")

Set wbDATA = Workbooks.Open("\\cmicro.com\Shares\Amb\Amb-Probes\DataLogs\CQS-03-033-2012 Coax Shelf Cut Log R2.6.xlsm", ReadOnly:=True)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With wbDATA.Sheets("ACP")

        LastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To LastRow

            val = .Cells(i, "E").Value
            Select Case val
                Case "Angle": col = "I"
                    NextRow = wsPasteTo.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Case "Vertical": col = "D"
                    NextRow = wsPasteTo.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                Case Else: col = "N"
                    NextRow = wsPasteTo.Range("N" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            End Select

            wsPasteTo.Cells(NextRow, col).Resize(1, 2).Value = .Cells(i, "K").Resize(1, 2).Value

        Next i

    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
wbDATA.Close False

End Sub
```

I forgot that the 'NextRow' for each type of data would be unique.

Thanks for your help Tim.